# How to set an x-offset for my whole linestring/layer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, layers, style

Supposing I have a layer imported from GeoServer succesfully, and it looks like this:
(some will remember me from my previous question. And, yes, that is my city Volos, Greece. There is a map and a blue `MultiLinestring`)

[image: example1]

Supposing this layer is offset by a few pixels by default to the left, which is the way to put it back where I want it.

How can I offset the whole LineString a few pixels to the right?

I tried this way:

```
var offsetStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({      
    graphicXOffset: 50000, 
    graphicYOffset: 50000
}); 

wms.style = offsetStyle;
```

But it doesn't work! The LineString will not move to the left or the right!

Can I do anything with QGIS to move my layer to the left or the right?

Comment: Is this Linestring a vector layer or a graphic or a wms. How are you requesting it from geoserver? If it is a vector layer, graphic offset won't do anything. If a wms, you can deal with it in the wms call. If a vector layer, you can iterate through the underlying geometry and move each point of the linestring a certain amount.

Comment: Hey @JohnBarça thanks for your answer once again! I figured out that the solution could come from QGIS. I used a plugin called 'Afine Transformation' and moved my whole layer to the left or right and then reloaded all of my data on the database and the geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the solution could come from a software called QGIS. I used a plugin called 'Afine Transformation' and moved my whole layer to the left or right and then reloaded all of my data on the database and the geoserver.